# How to toggle between HEX and normal view (ASCII) in UltraEdit?

Tags: hex, ultraedit

How can you go back to the normal ASCII view, instead of the HEX view?

I know it is possible, but I forgot where and how. See beneath the situation I want to change.

[image: HEX situation before]

Comment: Your question and answer would not be necessary if you would have opened help of UltraEdit, opened the page __Hex Edit command__ from __Index__ or __Contents__ tab and read at least the first two sentences.

Comment: Well, I did open the help file but apparantly did not found the right starting point. Also did different searches with Google. Because I could not find a quick answer I decided to add a q and a when I found the answer. For my own future reference and benefit of others.

Comment: It would be interesting how you searched in help, i.e. which words you have used on help tab __Search__? By using `HEX ASCII` as search term the first item in results list is __Hex Edit command__. Also when using `ascii hex view` the __Hex Edit command__ is at top of the results list. Even with just `ASCII view` the __Hex Edit command__ is in results list as third item. However, your question is definitely off-topic for Stack Overflow as this site is for programming. It is acceptable to ask here also questions about a text editor, but only if being in context of writing or compiling code.

Comment: I searched on "toggle ultraedit to normal mode", "I dont want view shown as hex in ultraedit", and the like. I think the question is in topic, because we (also) use UE to do programming. So having UE working like desired is imperative to be able to programme. But maybe indeed this q and can be put elsewhere. Let's see what the community or administrator decides. In any case in my opinion this title of the q will help some people that have the same issue find a solution quicker.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that when in HEX view, by pressing 'HEX edit'/mode, you get back to ASCII mode. Or better said: you toggle.

I guess I unconsciously expected a 'ASCII mode' button. See the printscreen how to toggle between the states.

Also the shortcut CTRL+H should work.

[image: After situation ASCII]